# C++ thread or concurrent processes

Tags: c++

How do we code a concurrent process A & B as follows:

- A and B subroutine start at the same time t0;
- A opens valve x then wait for 5 seconds, then open valve y, then wait until z is closed, then close both x and y;
- B open valve z, then wait 10 sec; then close valve z;

Should I use thread then?

Comment: Before coding, **analyze** the thing. Realize that it's possible for A to, uh, close both x and y before B opens valve z.

Comment: Since there is no concept of a valve in C++, I doubt the tag is placed correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify - A cannot close x and y until B closes z

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library only supports synchronization of concurrent executions for threads. So if you're limited to the standard library you have to use threads. Otherwise, choose whatever API that's OK with your professor or textbook.